# Show that it is not a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$T[x\; \; y]^T$ = $[0\; \; y^2]^T$

I have tried using the two conditions to prove that it is not. However, I'm not sure how to apply them in this case. $T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y), T(ax) = aT(x)$.

Comment: $$T((-1,1)+(1, -1))= T(0,0)=(0,0) \neq (0,2) =(0,1)+(0,1)= T(1,-1)+T(1,-1)$$

Comment: This is one of the exercizes of the type "come on, try it!". Almost *any* choice of $x,y$ would provide a counterexample. If you are not sure how to do it is because you didn't even try.

Answer (score 1):

$T(a(x,y))=(0,(ay)^{2})=a^{2}(0,y^{2})\neq a(0,y^{2})=aT(x,y).$